# Iphone and Android Unity approach

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I have a couple of questions.

I been working on Unity about one month now, our idea on Unity is that we have a multiplatform framework, and that it would be less expensive, however i can see a lot of things are iphone or android, for example the touch inputs.

How should i make an approach dealing with a game that need to be in both platforms?.

What's the main difference between these different inputs?

Thanks

Comment: You might wanna try the game dev forums on here

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using [FingerGestures](http://fingergestures.fatalfrog.com/), available from the Asset Store in Unity3D. We work on projects with various targets and, thanks to that library, we have no issues handling inputs. It's inexpensive and uses delegates to subscribe to events!

The two libs I always include in my projects are FingerGestures and [iTween](http://itween.pixelplacement.com/index.php) (including the add-on GameObject integration).